# Synonyms file error to parsing

Tags: java, solr

I have problem with add synonyms.. One synonym work, other not.. I don't know how it works. Where is difference between `=>` and `,`
schema.xml

```
<analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />               
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>       
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>   
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" synonyms="premorfologiksynonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>   
    <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" dictionary="MORFOLOGIK" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>    
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>              
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" synonyms="premorfologiksynonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>   
    <filter class="solr.MorfologikFilterFactory" dictionary="MORFOLOGIK" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
  </analyzer>
```

Comment: Can you add your file `synonyms.txt` and your `schema.xml`?

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. I already found fault. My bad.. I add a synonyms like this: `somet => smth => something` but now I need a help with synonyms. When i want to search hp102 in this word how can I write this synonym? my synonym filter is after `<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />               
  <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"/>  
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> `. So when my string is splitted i trying to add synonym after this split so not `h/p 102` but `h p 102 => hp102`. Nothing works fine..

Comment: You need to have a synonym for `h/p 102` which is splitted before you try to use synonyms. So you try to make a matching between `h p 102` and `hp102` in your synonym file. Is that right?

Comment: If yes, why not using option of  `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`? https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory

Comment: I edited first post. Its my schema.xml and there is `WordDelimiterFilterFactory`

Comment: Yes but but without any option. For example, if you use option `catenateAll=1`, you can create 2 tokens: `hp` and `102`.

Comment: so for example i want that line `grip, ultra grip, ultragip, ug` this all words solr find identically. If i ask solr to find `ultra grip performance` then i got only this product where productname have `ug performance`, `ultragrip performance` or `ug performance` And when i ask `ug performance` i want this same but without `ug`. So this option not support this  or what ?